# How do I prevent form input data from being reset when I remove and re-append the form element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have a form that needs to be appended elsewhere in the DOM, and when that occurs all form inputs return to their original values. Is there a way to retain the form input values when the form element is removed and re-appended? I'm using jQuery and the append() function.

Comment: Have you looked at `.clone()`? I believe the `.clone()` method with the `withDataAndEvents` argument as `true` will copy the form, events and data including form values.

Comment: clone(true) doesn't seem to copy the current input value - it copies events and data entered using the data() function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what worked for me:

Before the form element is cloned using .clone(true):

```
$('#MyForm :input').each(function() { 
    $(this).data('val',$(this).val()); 
});
```

After the cloned form element is append()'d:

```
$('#MySameFormSomewhereElseInTheDOM :input').each(function() {
     $(this).val($(this).data('val')); 
});
```